# It is possible to authenticate in Yammer and Outlook with rest api?

Tags: graph, oauth-2.0, yammer, outlook-api

I am trying to integrate Yammer and Outlook using the Rest API, I can read the emails but I have an error returned when reading data from yammer. The documentation is unclear about it, can they help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow one of the [authentication flows](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2) outlined within a browser window.

Typically you would popup a window with a browser control to do this work and then securely store the OAuth token returned. I recommend working through the flow by hand before writing code to integrate it. It is expected that a user sees and has to agree to an OAuth dialog like the one shown.

You then pass the token on the authorization header like this with your HTTP requests:

```
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Brian, but I'm using Graph's endpoint, I'd like to use Outlook and Yammer together.

```
var authEndpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?';
var apiEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/api/v2.0';
```

I would not like to authenticate again, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add `resource=https://www.yammer.com` param to the  authEndpoint to be able to access yammer data. See this blog post for further details - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2016/07/05/yammer-apis-and-adal-tokens/